# spplot with layers are not aligned

Tags: r, raster

I'm trying to overlay an Italy boundary map on a ggmap. I'm using spplot but the layers aren't aligned.

This is my code:

```
library(raster)
library(ggmap)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(latticeExtra)

setwd("c:\\temp")
gadm<-getData('GADM', country='Italy', level=2)
bbPoints <- bbox(gadm) 
gmap <- get_map(c(bbPoints), maptype='watercolor', source='stamen', crop=FALSE)

bbMap <- attr(gmap, 'bb')

height <- with(bbMap, ur.lat - ll.lat)
width <- with(bbMap, ur.lon - ll.lon)
latCenter <- with(bbMap, ll.lat + ur.lat)/2
lonCenter <- with(bbMap, ll.lon + ur.lon)/2

spplot(gadm, "PID",border="green",col=NA)+
layer(grid.raster(gmap,x=lonCenter, y=latCenter,
width=width, height=height,
default.units='native'), under = TRUE)
```

[image]

To center the layers I followed this tutorial: http://www.r-bloggers.com/stamen-maps-with-spplot/

I don't understand why automatic centering doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem related to the projection (or absence of it) of the objects returned by `ggmap`. There is an interesting discussion about it in [this thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2014-April/020911.html) and [a tutorial](http://rpubs.com/alobo/vectorOnraster) using `dismo::gmap` instead. I must update my blog post to include this issue.